# What areas in London, Manchester, and Edinburgh should I avoid?

Tags: uk, safety, religion

Are there places in the UK where the frequency of attacks on the non-white population is prevalent, especially on Muslims?

What areas in **London**, **Manchester**, and **Edinburgh** should I avoid as a non-white tourist, and if I wear a hijab?

Also, is it safe to move around during soccer matches; or national or Christian days?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138458/discussion-on-question-by-user366312-what-areas-in-london-manchester-and-edinb).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Based on the latest available statistics, racially- or religiously-motivated attacks are not massively widespread in the UK. For example, while racially motivated hate crimes (85,268 offences) increased by 12 per cent between year ending March 2020 and year ending March 2021, religious hate crimes fell by 18 per cent (from 6,856 to 5,627. Putting that in context, the UK’s population is approaching 70million, of which the Muslim population is around 4% AFAIK.

Source: https://www.gov.uk/government/statistics/hate-crime-england-and-wales-2020-to-2021/hate-crime-england-and-wales-2020-to-2021

Every city in the UK has areas where crime and anti-social behaviour is more prevalent than elsewhere. If you’re visiting the UK as a tourist you’re probably unlikely to go anywhere near such areas. In general, national holidays and major sporting events are perfectly safe for all. The UK does not have a gun culture; shooting incidents are still relatively rare. Sadly, knife crime is increasing, especially amongst teenagers.

If you’re concerned, research the areas you intend to visit before you travel. The usual personal safety precautions apply wherever you go, of course eg https://www.victimsupport.org.uk/help-and-support/keeping-safe/personal-safety/ and https://www.met.police.uk/cp/crime-prevention/personal-safety-how-to-stay-safe/pickpocketing/

You could also try contacting the Muslim Council of Great Britain for advice https://mcb.org.uk/

Comment: Of course, those numbers are only those actually reported to the police, but certainly give a sense of scale.

Comment: @origimbo Of course, however IMHO the UK is not the hotbed of racial /religious unrest that some elements of the media like to portray.  Not saying it doesn’t exist, just that in general the UK is a safe place to visit irrespective of gender, race, religion etc

Comment: Most countries aren't the hotbed of racial unrest that the media likes to portray. It's just that `Race A` on `Race B` crimes make the headlines while `Race A` on `Race A` crimes are buried on the back page of the police blotter section. (For those who remember what a newspaper was.)

Comment: It is perhaps useful to link to the definition of 'hate crime', which spans a wide range: https://www.cps.gov.uk/crime-info/hate-crime

Comment: @avid There’s a definition in s1.2 of the report linked in my answer :-)

Comment: @Traveller Well that's just too obvious!